How to filter a queryset by a many2many field
I have a Notification model which has a field called seen_users like so:
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

class Notification(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    seen_users = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)

Whenever a user sees a notification (.e.g notification_obj), that user will be added to notification_obj.seen_users.
Now how can I filter notifications that has not seen by a specific user like user1  In most efficient way?
I've tried to query like below:
class NotificationView(generics.ListAPIView):
    authentication_classess = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = []

    def get_queryset(self):
        unseen_only = self.request.GET.get("unseen_only", "0")
        if unseen_only == "1":
            
            # THIS IS WHERE I GOT TROUBLES
            # Because other users may have seen this and its not empty
            return Notification.objects.filter(seen_users__in=[]) 

        return Notification.objects.all()


Use .exclude(…) [Django-doc]:
Notification.objects.exclude(seen_users=request.user)
This will thus exclude the Notifications from the queryset where request.user is a member.


Note: It is normally better to make use of the settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL [Django-doc] to refer to the user model, than to use the User model [Django-doc] directly. For more information you can see the referencing the User model section of the documentation.


Thanks. It works. About the note, get_user_model does the thing, doesn't it? –
@willeM

@AbbasEbadian: it requires the django.contrib.auth to be loaded first, or the app where the user model is located, so it adds an extra dependency, which settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL requires not.
